# v-bind data not updating in vue component template

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

When Object is updated in vue component, the Dom is not updating, even though it is connected with v-bind.

```js
parasails.registerComponent('recipe-form', {
    //  ╔═╗╦═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗
    //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║ ║╠═╝╚═╗
    //  ╩  ╩╚═╚═╝╩  ╚═╝
    props: [
      'recipe' //this is an object like {name: 'name', ingredientPhoto: '/images/no-image.png' }
    ],

    template: `
<ajax-form :action="currentPath === '/recipes/create-recipe' ? 'createRecipe' : 'updateRecipe'"
               :syncing.sync="syncing" :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" v-on:submitted="submittedForm($event)"
               :handle-parsing="handleParsingForm">

<!--- some html removed for clarity ---->

<div class="card">
              <img id="ingredient-photo-thumbnail" v-if="recipe.ingredientPhoto" class="thumbnail w-100" v-bind:src="recipe.ingredientPhoto" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="ingredient-photo" id="ingredient-photo-input" accept="image/*"
                           @change="uploadFile('ingredientPhoto', $event)">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="custom-file-input">Ingredients Photo</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<!--- src attribute does not change when recipe.ingredientPhoto is updated in method ---->

</ajax-form>
`,


    methods: {

      async uploadFile(photoType, event) {
        //simplified for clarity
        this.recipe.ingredientPhoto = `https://example.com/photo.jpg`;
        console.log(this.recipe); //this is logging the updated recipe.ingredientPhoto property as expected but it's not updating the img src in Dom
      }
    })
}
```

I don't understand why it's updating the data object property `recipe.ingredientPhoto` but not updating the field that is synced with `v-bind`. The same method works if I try it at the parent level but not the component level.

How can I get the `src` attribute to update when `recipe.ingredientPhoto` is updated?

Comment: Your component should not be updating its `props`. That's not how Vue's one-way data flow works. What does the parent component look like? What value is it passing for the `recipe` prop?

Comment: You are not suppose to mutate props locally in your component, try to use computed or a watcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), your component should emit the new image URL value up to the parent where it can make the appropriate change.

For example, in the parent

```html
<recipe-form :recipe="recipe" @uploaded="uploaded"></recipe-form>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  // make sure all required properties are defined
  recipe: {
    ingredientPhoto: null // or whatever makes sense as a default value
  }
}),
methods: {
  uploaded (photoUrl) {
    this.recipe.ingredientPhoto = photoUrl
  }
}
```

and in your component's `uploadFile` method

```js
this.$emit('uploaded', 'https://example.com/photo.jpg') // from your example
```